# Responsive web page: Unable to center content using margin: 0 auto have width on all containers

Tags: responsive-design, margin, center, percentage

sorry I know similar questions have been asked but I still can't work it out. I want the images in the body to be centered but only when the aspect ratio means that there is white space on the right hand side, I have tried using margin: 0 auto but to no avail.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="landscape">
        <img class="topslide" src="images/background/topslide.jpg"/>


        <img class="middleslide" src="images/background/middleslide.jpg"/>


      <img class="bottomslide" src="images/background/bottomslide.jpg"/>

    </div>

    <div id="portrait">
        <img class="topslide" src="images/background/topslideland.jpg"/>


        <img class="middleslide" src="images/background/middleslideland.jpg"/>


      <img class="bottomslide" src="images/background/bottomslideland.jpg"/>

    </div>

</body>
```

And here is my css:

```
html{
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
}
body{
margin:0px auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: url(../image/background/background.jpg) ;    
}     
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
#landscape {display:block;}
#portrait {display:none;}
}
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
#landscape {display:none;}
#portrait {display:block;}
}
#landscape{
margin: 0 auto;
}
#portrait{
margin: 0 auto;
}
 img.topslide{
display:block;   
max-width:100vw;
height:33.3vh;
}
img.middleslide{
display:block;    
max-width:100vw;
height:33.3vh;
}
img.bottomslide{
display:block;    
max-width:100vw;
height:33.3vh;
}
```

I'll be grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you misunderstood what `margin: 0 auto` does. It doesn't center the contents of an element; it centers the element itself.

Give your `#landscape` and `#portrait` their own `width`, or apply `margin: 0 auto` to the images. Either you'll center the images or their containers. Or both, should you find it necessary.

An alternative approach to center the images would be to `display` your images as `inline-block` and apply `text-align: center` to their parents.